# Can I know what index MultiReader got a document from?

Tags: lucene

I have a [MultiReader](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/MultiReader.html) connected to several indexes.

After I run a query and get the results, is there a way to know from which index the result was from?

I know it's not exactly what MultiReader is for. I still need this.

Comment: curious, what is your usecase for that need?

Comment: also, I dont see any easy way of doing that, olny possibility is to extend Lucene classes, cause CompositeReader have ids for different sources.

Answer (score 2):

You can *if you are the one who create `MultiReader` instance*.

You can  extend that class and implement required functionality. `BaseCompositeReader` (super type of `MultiReader`) has `readerIndex()` and `getSequentialSubReaders()` methods. So following code should work:

```
public static class MyMultiReader extends MultiReader {

    public MyMultiReader(IndexReader... subReaders) throws IOException {
        super(subReaders);
    }

    public IndexReader getReaderForDocument(int docId) {
        return getSequentialSubReaders().get(readerIndex(docId));
    }
}
```